# iCloud icon not shown when uploading to server

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, icloud

Good day everyone,

I faced something weird & don't know the reason behind it. I've a UIWebView which displayes a normal HTML page with an upload button.

The problem is that iCloud option is not shown on device,

[image: Notice the vertical scroll indicator]

in contrary with simulator

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

p.s have you noticed the vertical scroll indicator in the first image? btw it's not scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found out the answer.
I have to have an account to member center and allow iCloud on my app.